# How To Fix Bottom navigation in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-bottomnavigation

How to fix Bottom Navigation in Flutter?

> MediaQuery.Of() called with context That does not contain a
>   MediaQuery.Bottom Navigation Not working.

This code Showing Error What is MediaQuery.Of() called with context That does not contain a MediaQuery?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main(){
  runApp(Home());
}
class Home extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _HomeState();



}
class _HomeState extends State<Home>{
  int currindex=0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Bottom Nav "),
      ),
      body: Container(),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: currindex,
        items:[BottomNavigationBarItem(
    icon: Icon(Icons.home),
    title: Text("Home"),
    backgroundColor: Colors.blue

    ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.search),
              title: Text("Search"),
              backgroundColor: Colors.blue

          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.person),
              title: Text("Profile"),
              backgroundColor: Colors.blue

          ),],
        onTap: (index){
          setState(() {
            currindex=index;

          });
        },

    ));
  }


}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Where are you using MediaQuery.of? It doesn't appear in the code snippet you have added.

Comment: Dont call `MediaQuery.of` inside of `MaterialApp build`

Answer (score 0):

it is because you are not using `MaterialApp()`, you need to use `MaterialApp()` in your widget tree

look at this demo....

```
    void main() => runApp(Home());

    class Home extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: //your Title,
          theme: //your theme,
          home: HomePage(),
        );
      }
    }

    class HomePage extends StatefulWidget{
      @override
      State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _HomePageState();
    }

//and your _HomePageState widget goes here
```